# Как найти номер строки и номер позиции в строке в текстовом файле?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно найти номер строки и номер позиции в строке заданого символа в текстовом файле.
Я сделал, но мне нужно считать символ не с начала, а с конца.
Посмотрите мой код (ищу первую . в файле):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int Search_position(int& i)
{
    ifstream fin("t.txt"); // название файла
    char line;
    int k = 0;
    while ((line = fin.get()) > 0) 
    {
        if (line == '.') 
        {
            k++;
            if (k == 1) 
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        if (line != '\n')
            i++;
    }
    cout << "No";
    return 0;
}

int Search_line(int& n, int& i)
{
    char line;
    int l = 0;
    ifstream fin("t.txt");
    while ((line = fin.get()) > 0) 
    {
        if (line != '\n')
            l++;
        if (l >= i && line == '\n')
            n++, l++;
    }
    return n;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ifstream fin("t.txt");
    char line[150];
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.getline(line, sizeof(line));
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    int i = 1;
    int n = 1;
    cout << "\nПозиция символа : " << Search_position(i) << endl;
    cout << "\nСтрока : " << Search_line(n, i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Text file:
One One
....
Two
Three
Four
..

Comment: Какой у вас вопрос? Что-то не работает? Что именно не работает? Как не работает?

Comment: у меня задача найти первую точку "." в текстовом файле, но чтобы искало с конца файла, у меня сделан поиск с начала файла, как сделать с конца?

Comment: Сейчас результат в програме такой:   Позиция символа: 8  Строка: 2

Comment: Вам нужно найти последнюю точку в файле?

Comment: нет, первую, но искать с конца файла

Comment: В чём разница между последней точкой и первой с конца? Приведите примеры, пожалуйста.